# How to plot POP2 grid (POP_gx1v7) data on map with xarray and cartopy?

Tags: grid, python-xarray, projection, cartopy, coordinate-transformation

I am working with ocean variables of the [LENS2 ensemble](https://www.cesm.ucar.edu/community-projects/lens2) of CESM2 and am now trying to plot the data on a geographical grid. The ocean model POP2 is based on a displaced-pole grid with poles in Greenland and Antarctica. The netCDF file contains the related WGS84 latitudes and longitudes but I do not manage to plot the data, especially north of 60 degree North.
I am conducting most of my work with `xarray` and would like to stay within this library, but if necessary I am also prepared to switch to other tools.

Ideally I would like to still be able to see the original grid cells instead of having the code interpolated. (Interpolation with `plt.contour()` works if I plot data below 60 degrees North. However, I need to plot data within the Nordic Seas and there the plot collapses.)

To show the problem, here is the simplest case:

```py
field = ds_temp.TEMP.isel(time=0, z_t=0)
extent = (ds_temp.TLONG.min(), ds_temp.TLONG.max(), 
          ds_temp.TLAT.min(), ds_temp.TLAT.max())

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
cs = ax.imshow(field, extent=extent, 
               origin='lower', 
               transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
plt.show()
```

This results in the following plot:

[image: plot with POP_gx1v7 data and cartopy PlateCarree projection]

As you can see the `cartopy` coastlines and the data’s land mask are shifted. How can I plot my `data` with `cartopy` and if possible staying with `xarray` functions?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the link to that netCDF file as well as the full code, clearly showing how you load the data set to "ds_temp". Anyway, you should probably check this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/461662/transforming-lat-lon-from-displaced-pole-grid-to-regular-wgs84-lat-lon

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `ax.coastlines()` you could try to draw your own coastlines around continents appearing as white areas on the map. Most likely, your orginal data in `field` has some invalid values for mainland areas of the map. If you print it, it could probably look something like this:

```
[[-1.7999999523162842 -1.7999999523162842 -1.7999999523162842 ...
  -1.7999999523162842 -1.7999999523162842 -1.7999999523162842]
 [-1.7999999523162842 -1.7999999523162842 -1.7999999523162842 ...
  -1.7999999523162842 -1.7999999523162842 -1.7999999523162842]
 [-1.7999999523162842 -1.7999999523162842 -1.7999999523162842 ...
  -1.7999999523162842 -1.7999999523162842 -1.7999999523162842]
 ...
 [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]]
```

Those double dashes look like missing data in [masked arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#module-numpy.ma). So one way to plot coastlines could be using [matplotlib.pyplot.contour](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) with a slightly modified data, where those "missing values" are replaced with some other ones, allowing you to compare them against a suitable threshold for drawing contours:

```py
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset

from cartopy import config
import cartopy.crs as ccrs


# get the path of the file -i t can be found in the repo data directory.
fname = os.path.join(config["repo_data_dir"],
                     'netcdf', 'HadISST1_SST_update.nc'
                     )

# get the data, latitudes and longtitudes
dataset = netcdf_dataset(fname)
sst = dataset.variables['sst'][0, :, :]
lats = dataset.variables['lat'][:]
lons = dataset.variables['lon'][:]

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# plot data
ax.contourf(lons,
             lats,
             sst,
             60,
             transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()
             )

# replace invalid values (corresponding to land) with some unrealistically high values
very_high_value = 100
fixed_sst = sst.filled(very_high_value)

# use a slightly smaller threshold value to plot contour lines around land
ax.contour(lons,
           lats,
           fixed_sst,
           levels=[very_high_value-1],
           colors='black',
           transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()
           )

plt.show()
```

The code above is based on [this example](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/advanced_plotting.html#contour-plots), showing the data with [matplotlib.pyplot.contourf](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html), and resulting in the following picture:
[image]

It doesn't look particularly nice, but it seems to do what you want. You will need to choose a suitable projection. If you use `imshow()` for plotting the original data, then you may need to adjust the `extent` parameters in `imshow()` and `contour()` separately.